# How do i disable textboxes based on what radio button is clicked in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to disable text the text boxes according to the radio button clicked but I can't figure out why they wouldn't disable.

HTML CODE (containing Textboxes and HTML)

```js
if (document.getElementById("cashbtn").checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("cardam").disabled = true;
        
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("cardbtn").checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("casham").disabled = true;
        
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("cashwcardbtn").checked)
        {
            document.getElementById("giftcheck").disabled = true;
        }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <h1>Payment Details</h1>
    
    <h3>Amount</h3>
    <input type="text" id="amounttxt">
    
    <h3>Payment Type</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashbtn">
    <label for="cash">Cash</label></br>
    
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cardbtn">
    <label for="card">Card</label></br>
    
    <input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashwcardbtn">
    <label for="cashwcard">Cash and Card</label></body></br>
    
    <h3>Gift Check</h3>
    <input type="text" id="giftcheck" >
    
    <h3>Cash Amount</h3>
    <input type="text" id="casham">
    
    <h3>Card Amount</h3>
    <input type="text" id="cardam"></br>
    
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: you need to somehow trigger that check don't you? like on click or some event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need event listeners to listen for the radio options.

```js
let radioBtns = document.getElementsByName('radAnswer')
Array.from(radioBtns).forEach(function (el) {
  el.onchange = function (e) {
    if (document.getElementById("cashbtn").checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("cardam").disabled = true;

    }
    else if (document.getElementById("cardbtn").checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("casham").disabled = true;

    }
    else if (document.getElementById("cashwcardbtn").checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("giftcheck").disabled = true;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>Payment Details</h1>

<h3>Amount</h3>
<input type="text" id="amounttxt">

<h3>Payment Type</h3>
<input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashbtn">
<label for="cash">Cash</label></br>

<input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cardbtn">
<label for="card">Card</label></br>

<input type="radio" name="radAnswer" id="cashwcardbtn">
<label for="cashwcard">Cash and Card</label></body></br>

<h3>Gift Check</h3>
<input type="text" id="giftcheck" >

<h3>Cash Amount</h3>
<input type="text" id="casham">

<h3>Card Amount</h3>
<input type="text" id="cardam"></br>

<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

</div>
```